# Emulate EL COERCE_TO_ZERO in Wildfly

Tags: jsf-2, el, wildfly-8

We're switching a JSF project from JBossAS 7.1.1 to Wildfly 8.2.0. However, this means that our EL version got bumped up from EL version 2.2 to EL 3.0 RI, which will not coerce empty numeric fields to zero when it gets passed to the backing bean.

Now I know that this is supposed to be the default behavior, but since our application depends on the EL parser to automatically convert null numeric values to zero, we would have to modify a large portion of our code.

Is there an option in EL 3.0 that will cause it to treat null numeric values as zero (as before), or is it possible for us to use EL 2.2 instead of EL 3.0 on Wildfly 8?